# Subaru Outback subtle vibration while turning

Tags: subaru, steering, vibration

My 2008 Subaru Outback has a gentle vibration I can feel in the steering and accelerator pedal and also a bit of noise associated with it.

At first I thought it was just the road but I noticed it gets slightly worse when I turn left and goes away completely when I turn right.

It feels/sounds like driving on rough asphalt.

Any ideas? I checked there's nothing rubbing on the wheels and power steering fluid is just bellow the "Max" marker.

I also tried putting gearbox in neutral and rolling through some fairly sharp corners at about 60kmh, it vibrates exactly the same as while driving normally - so probably not related to the engine or transmission.

Comment: I'm thinking it would either have to do with a wheel bearing or the drive shaft on the right side, but don't know for sure.

Comment: By "drive shaft", you mean "axle", right, @Paulster2? Not the driveshaft going to the rear diff.

Comment: @JoshCaswell ... Yes, axle shaft would be a better name, you are right.

Comment: Whatever it is, sounds serious. I've booked it in with my mechanic and will post an answer once it's fixed.

Comment: I would check axle bearings when the car is up on the lift.

Comment: Does it have aftermarket rims and/or tyres?

Comment: It might also be that your wheel speed sensor is dirty. This sensor is used by your ABS and traction control.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert: Did you ever find out the source of the problem?

Comment: @Ellesedil bearings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be the steering rack or bad wheel bearings.

Comment: Please explain why you believe this to be the right answer ... it will help you over the long run. Answers with some meat are better received, as long as the meat isn't fluff.

Comment: It was the bearings.

Answer (score 0):

It could be oddly worn tires or ..If the 'OutBack' means you go 4-wheeling
in harsh terrain ,you may bend the frame of the vehicle even to the point
of setting off the air-bags.

Comment: By Outback, he's talking about a [specific model](http://www.subaru.com/vehicles/outback/index.html) of vehicle ... I'm pretty sure in this instance it has nothing to do with Australia.